# What is the word for a list of photographs taken by a photographer?

Tags: photography

There is filmography for films, bibliography for books, discography for music, but I can't seem to find one for photographs.

Answer (score 2):

One word that comes to mind is *portfolio*.

This is often used for a selected subset of works, rather than all the works of a photographer. However, if you make it clear what you mean by context, the word *portfolio* works.

Another possible word is [catalogue raisonée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalogue_raisonn%C3%A9).

This is a compiled list of an artists' entire life output. The Wikipedia article I have linked to makes it clear that compiling it can be a very time-consuming undertaking, unlike a novelists' bibliography or a musical groups' discography, because artists produce many more individual works of art than novelists.